# Как очистить JSON данные из браузера?

Tags: javascript, json

Добрый день,
у меня есть проблема с формой регистрацией и ее валидацией.

Когда пользователь вводит в форму почту, валидатор проверяет не занят ли эта почта, делает запрос и получает JSON данные с сервера через ajax. Если пользователь введет новую почту, валидатор повторит операцию, но если ввести первую почту в форму, то валидатор ничего запрашивать уже не будет потому что у него уже есть эти данные. Данные будут храниться до тех пор пока не будет перезагружен страница, а я хочу удалить эти данные после того как закроется попап, тк их наличие может привести к ошибке, например если пользователь попытается повторно зарегистрироваться в системе.

И так вопрос, как удалить эти данные после закрытия попапа
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: данные json ничем не отличаются от других данных. В 99% случаев нужно просто присвоить переменной, которая хранит json либо пустую строку (если json данные в виде строки), либо пустой json.

Comment: Честно говоря код не мой, и я не знаю куда он их сохраняет, вижу что содержимое можно прочитать в инспекторе браузера во вкладке Network, отфильтровать можно по XHR, там можно найти все запросы полученные ранее.

Comment: Это значит только то, что браузер их получил. Сохранял ли он их - а кто его знает

Comment: Если я повторю условия при котором браузер должен повторно запросить данные с сервера, браузер увидит что эти данные у него уже есть и не запросит их повторно. Те если я ему веду в форму Почту№1, а потом почту№2, валидатор проверит заняты эти почтовые ящики или нет, и пришлет с сервера данные об этом, но если я ему введу повторно почту№1, браузер не будет запрашивать эти данные с сервера, тк они у него уже есть.

Comment: Выложите пример кода где emails сохраняются.

Answer (score -1):

Вопрос решился путем принудительной актуализации данных.

$.ajax({
    actualize: true,
    ....

Валидатор теперь запрашивает ответ от сервера каждый раз, когда проводит проверку, даже если он уже проверял эти значения и у него есть нужный ответ от сервера для аналогичного запроса.

т.е. не смотря на то что у валидатора уже есть данные для этого запроса, он все равно при каждой проверке будет запрашивать данные повторно, собственно это и исправляет в дальнейшем баг с хранящимися в браузере не актуальными данными.

Comment: Ответ ужасный. Вы не ответили на вопрос. Из этого ответа не понятно ровным счётом ничего!

Comment: Я обновил.
Суть решения в том, что валидатор не проверяет уже имеющиеся ответы от сервера, а запрашивает для каждого случаю повторно, даже если он уже запрашивал у сервера эти данные

Comment: Ответ, по-прежнему, ужасен. Ужасает хотя бы это `$.ajax({ actualize: true,....`

Comment: собственно это и было единственное изменение в коде,
тк как я код ранее не выкладывал, я объяснил суть изменения текстом выше